# How to deploy Azure function app that uses code from a private GitHub repository

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, github-actions

I am trying to deploy a python Azure function app that has a reference to a private github repository in it's requirements. This repository contains common utility code that would be used in multiple function apps.

The repository is added to requirements.txt as follows:

git+https://github.com/#user#/#library#.git@main

When deploying from VS Code directly, the deployment fails because of authentication issues to that repository.

I have tried to tackle this issue by using GitHub actions pipeline with SSH-authentication. I have setup a pipeline where I authenticate to that repository via SSH and then I am able to deploy the function app. The problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes it won't. The deployment pipeline succeeds, but on occasions, the changes in code are not applied to the function app.

So my question is: Has anyone tried using private Github repositories as dependencies for function apps and how have you solved the deployment problem?

Comment: How did you solve this in the end? One solutions seems to embed the token in the dependency listed in your requirements.txt however there must be a better way